# What do you do when you are in IT honeymoon?

Tags: fulltime

Working full-time in the IT/Telecom industry, either as a developer, sysadmin, devops, etc;  There are cases when the projects/jobs are done and there is nothing else to do, so basically when someone has nothing else to do, they use to say, he/she is in "honeymoon".

There is always something that can be done, improve, research or learn, but what are some practices used by companies to keep they employees motivated and in good shape.

From a personal perspective you can do many things, but question is more related about how the project managers, companies deal with this cases, they fire people, change company hiring policies and go for freelancers etc.

Comment: Whatever you do, look busy. Or else everyone will hold a grudge on you, especially your boss.

Comment: Do you have any references for that use of the term? I've never heard it before and not finding anything in a cursory search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with that I am first time poster on this particular SO board, so be gentle ;).

Also your title asks about what we do when we have no work left at work. The body though asks what companies do to keep their employees motivated and in good shape. Possibly two questions?

Quite a few the places I worked at, when such situations arose, would usually ask to:

- Help with outstanding issues on other systems I was involved in,
- Mentor junior team members with regards to technology stack we were developing in (not everyone is nolife like me, I dive in and have fun with it in and out of work and we all know how hard it is to try your best when you have knowledge but only a slight idea of how to actually approach a problem),
- Ask to do some research of technologies they have on their road-map to do R&D
- Take a look at current processes (deployments for example)and see if they can be automated a little bit (for example if deployment days are pain in the booty and you end up spending time after that fixing stuff),
- Spend time learning - new tech that could potentially be relevant, brush up our skills in areas you are not confident, etc.

One piece of advice is to *ask*, not just sit there making yourself look busy. If management is not aware of the fact you are not busy, they will not ask you to do anything.

If they are aware and don't have anything for you, propose what you think would be the most beneficial use of your time (mentoring, research, getting your knowledge updated, etc.). This could potentially go down as being "proactive" (Got to love mgmt buzzword bingo...).

I wrote this post not accounting for situations when "proactive" approach would be taken by anyone as negative behaviour - ie managers afraid you will replace them.

--
Let me also add what I understood by "honeymoon period" at work - it usually, in broader sense means the initial first couple of weeks after you started new job - you know, your head is still in the clouds and you didn't have enough exposure to the environment - in your mind it's the best job ever, you might not have to do much initially and nothing will change... until honeymoon period is over.